# simple nginx reverse proxy seems to strip some headers

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I am a beginner at nginx.  I have a simple webserver on 8080 that I want to pass all traffic to in this rather small environment.  My proxy seems to work except that a custom header is not there when it gets to my upstream server.  The server block is below.  What would I need to add to this to keep my custom header?  In this case the custom header was set in angularjs but I don't think that has anything to do with it as it works fine going directly to 8080 on the server.  ($httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['GH_client'] = client_id();)

```
server {
server_name localhost;

location / {
        proxy_pass      http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_redirect  off;
    proxy_pass_header X-CSRF-TOKEN;
        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy true;
}}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your header contains underscore (`_`). By default, nginx treats headers with an underscore as invalid and drops them.

You should enable [`underscores_in_headers`](http://nginx.org/r/underscores_in_headers) directive.

Otherwise, consider changing the header name to one without underscores. `GH-client` will be perfectly valid and proxied to your backend server.

Comment: If you're using nginx in an AWS environment you might be interested in [this thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=674114)

Comment: Thanks.  MVC .net's default CSRF header defaults to underscores. We ran into this today.

Comment: Thanks, the same problem for me, worked locally but remote deployment with ngix always failed.