# Html.AntiForgeryToken() still required?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, antiforgerytoken

Is `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` still required in ASP.NET .NET4.6 vNext?

The form decorations have changed to

```html
<form asp-controller="Account" 
      asp-action="Login" 
      asp-route-returnurl="@ViewBag.ReturnUrl" 
      method="post" 
      class="form-horizontal" 
      role="form">
```

From this

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", 
                       "Account", 
                       new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, 
                       FormMethod.Post, 
                       new { @class = "", role = "form" }))
```

And no longer include this

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

The Controller Actions are still marked with the `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` attribute as expected though so where exactly is it coming from? Automagically?

```cs
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The form tag helper will automatically add the anti forgery token. (Unless you use it as a standard html form element, manually adding an `action` attribute). Check the source code of the [form tag helper](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers/FormTagHelper.cs), you will see the following at the end of the `Process` method.

```
if (Antiforgery ?? antiforgeryDefault)
{
    var antiforgeryTag = Generator.GenerateAntiforgery(ViewContext);
    if (antiforgeryTag != null)
    {
        output.PostContent.AppendHtml(antiforgeryTag);
    }
}
```

If you check the html of the login page, you will see the following hidden input inside the form:

```
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="CfDJ8BIeHClDdT9...">
```

You can also manually enable/disable it adding the `asp-antiforgery` attribute:

```
<form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register" asp-antiforgery="false" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
```

Comment: As of MVC 6, Asp.net 5 RC1 the Tag Helper is "asp-antiforgery" not "asp-anti-forgery" not sure if it was already like that or changed.  <br/>

`<form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register" asp-antiforgery="false" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">`

Comment: it also seems that the <form> needs a separate closing tag </form> for this attribute to generate. it does not seem to work with a self-closing form tag <form/>. maybe because self-closing form tags are not valid HTML5, in which case the lack of a compiler or even a runtime error is still annoying

Comment: You say `(Unless you use it as a standard html form element, manually adding an action attribute)` But what if the form points to itself with no action attribute at all?