# Using the antiforgery cookie in ASP.NET Core but with a non-default CookieName

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm thinking about changing name of the default antiforgery cookie in ASP.NET Core.

The reason why I would like to change the cookie name is to anonymize the cookie, in my opinion there is no reason why end users should be able to determine the responsibility of this cookie.

[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryOptions.CookieName](https://docs.asp.net/projects/api/en/latest/autoapi/Microsoft/AspNetCore/Antiforgery/AntiforgeryOptions/index.html#prop-Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryOptions.CookieName)

1. How do I change the name of the antiforgery cookie? I guess it should be done in the **Startup.cs** file in somehow?
2. What possible implications could occur by changing name the default antiforgery cookie?
3. How do I use the antiforgery cookie in ASP.NET Core?
4. Should different web applications (using same domain) share single antiforgery cookie, or should separate antiforgery cookies be created for each web application?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can set a different name in your `Startup.ConfigureServices` as in:

```
services.AddAntiforgery(opts => opts.CookieName = "MyAntiforgeryCookie");
```

For [.Net Core 2.0.0 or greater there will be changes](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/257):

Reference: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryOptions?view=aspnetcore-2.0

For that use following:

```
services.AddAntiforgery(opts => opts.Cookie.Name = "MyAntiforgeryCookie");
```

By default `AddMvc()` internally calls `AddAntiforgery()`, which means you get the default cookie, header and form names. If you need to/want to use different names, you can do so by manually calling AddAntiforgery as above.

There should be no implications for your application if you change the cookie name (unless you added code yourself that manually used that cookie). You might also want to change the header/form name, for example the offical Antiforgery repo [has an example](https://github.com/aspnet/Antiforgery/blob/dev/samples/AntiforgerySample/Startup.cs) that uses Angular and changes the header as the standard angular XSRF token header.

In order to use it, add the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` to controller actions other than GET requests.

You have to do nothing else for standard html forms as long as you use the asp form tag helpers, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30959972/html-antiforgerytoken-still-required).

If you use ajax requests, then you will need to include either a header or a field within your request that includes the generated token. You basically need to:

1. Get an `IAntiforgery`
2. Call `var tokenSet = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(httpContext);`
3. Make it available to your js code so it knows about the value `tokenSet.RequestToken` to be included as either a field with name `tokenSet.FormFieldName` or a header with name `tokenSet.HeaderName` within each ajax request.

   - A few options for that like rendering the token into a JS object inside a script section in your js layout, adding a JS readable cookie as in the angular example, keep rendering hidden fields you include within the ajax request
   - There is a nice overview of the options [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20504846/why-is-it-common-to-put-csrf-prevention-tokens-in-cookies)

The aim is for POST/PUT/DELETE/PATCH requests to include 2 things:

- the antiforgery cookie
- the field/header with the token

So the antiforgery middleware can validate there was no XSRF.

---

**Update about cookie name/domain**

The sensible default is for each application to have its own cookie. You mostly get that with the default approach as no domain is specifically set on the cookie, so the cookie takes the domain from the request. That would mean different cookies for different applications unless the appliacations are hosted with the same domain.

- Read more about how cookies work [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062963/how-do-browser-cookie-domains-work/1063760#1063760)

You might only want to share the cookie in special cases, for example if you have 2 applications where a form in app A posts to app B. In those cases make sure you use a domain/subdomain that matches both applications and both use the same cookiea name.

- Read more about XSRF [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: Should different ASP.NET Core web applications have different cookie name on the antiforgery cookie? When using the default antiforgery cookie there is only one .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.xxxxxxx in the user browser...

Comment: Cookies without specific domain get stored for the domain of the request, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1063760/1836935). Maybe you are running locally several sites so they all have localhost as domain? I also noticed  they have [recently changed Antiforgery](https://github.com/aspnet/Antiforgery/commit/08cb67b7e45c88eaba26a6c68b9f82a5608582d6) so the `AntiforgeryOptions` expose new `CookieDomain` and `CookiePath` properties.

Comment: Yes currently all my web applications share same domain and this is probably the reason why only one antiforgery cookie is created. But is this a recommended approach or should each web application have separate antiforgery cookie? I added this to the question.

Comment: A sensible default would be each application having its own cookie. You mostly get that with the default approach as no domain is specifically set on the cookie, so the cookie assumes the domain for the request. You might only want to share the cookie in special cases, for example if you have 2 applications where a form in one posts to the second app. In that case make sure you set the cookie name and domain in both applications.

Comment: What does it mean when my webpage does not generate the default cookie?