# What is .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.xxxxxxx cookie in .Net Core?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, antiforgerytoken

I was trying to use ValidateAntiForgeryToken in .Net Core but I was getting .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.xxxxxxx cookie is missing.

What is this .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.xxxxxxx cookie?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

ASP.NET Core looks for this cookie to find the X-CSRF token.

> The `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` is an action filter that can be applied to an individual action, a controller, or globally for the app. Requests made to actions that have this filter applied will be blocked unless the request includes a valid antiforgery token.

In general ASP.NET Core may look for the token in cookie or header. So you may have the situation when

- instead of cookie the header is used to pass token
- cookie with token has the different name than the ASP.NET Core expected.

By default, the ASP.NET Core will generate and expect a unique cookie name beginning with the DefaultCookiePrefix (".AspNetCore.Antiforgery.").

This could be overriden using an antiforgery option `CookieName`:

```
services.AddAntiforgery(options => options.CookieName = "X-CSRF-TOKEN-COOKIENAME");
```

For [.Net Core 2.0.0 or greater there will be changes](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/257):

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryOptions?view=aspnetcore-2.0

For that use following:

```
services.AddAntiforgery(options => options.Cookie.Name = "X-CSRF-TOKEN-COOKIENAME");
```

If talking about header, name could be specified by:

```
services.AddAntiforgery(options => options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN");
```

---

Look into:

- [Preventing Cross-Site Request Forgery (XSRF/CSRF) Attacks in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery)
- readme in [Antiforgery repo](https://github.com/aspnet/Antiforgery) contains links to samples
- SO: [Using the antiforgery cookie in ASP.NET Core but with a non-default CookieName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40511103/using-the-antiforgery-cookie-in-asp-net-core-but-with-a-non-default-cookiename)

Comment: Or ... If `Antiforgery` is somehow already added by default, you can configure it in the way shown here: https://github.com/aspnet/Antiforgery/issues/97#issue-169311974