# CRUD Update in .net Core and cshtml

Tags: javascript, html, .net, model-view-controller

I apologize in advance if this is a simple question, I am studying .net and I really want to be able to make an Update function
I have created a .net 6 MVC solution

I created a CardsController:

```
    public class CardsController : Controller {

        private readonly CardsContext _context;
        public CardsController(CardsContext context) {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult Index() {
            var cards = _context.Cards.ToList();
            return View(cards);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Create() {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Create([Bind("Title,Description,Stage,Tag")] CardsModel cardsModel) {
            if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                _context.Add(cardsModel);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(cardsModel);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Update(int? id) {
            if (id == null) {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var cardsModel = _context.Cards.Find(id);
            if (cardsModel == null) {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(cardsModel);
        }

        [HttpPut]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Update(int id, [FromBody] CardsModel cardsModel) {

            if(id != cardsModel.id) {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                try {
                    _context.Update(cardsModel);
                    _context.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException) {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }

            return View(cardsModel);

        }

        [HttpDelete]
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            
            if (id == null){
                return NotFound();
            }

            var cardsModel = _context.Cards.Find(id);

            if(cardsModel == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.Cards.Remove(cardsModel);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));

        }


    }
```

I created a route for my actions:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Cards}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "Delete",
                    pattern: "Cards/Delete/{id?}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Cards", action = "Delete" });
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "Update",
                    pattern: "Cards/Update/{id?}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Cards", action = "Update" });
            });
```

I created a  function in cshtml for the Delete and Update:

```
<script>
    function deleteCard(id) {
        fetch('/Cards/Delete/' + id, {
            method: 'Delete'
        })
            .then(response => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    alert('Success!');
                } else {
                    alert('Error.');
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                alert('Error.');
                console.error(error);
            });
    }

    function UpdateCard(id) {
        fetch(`/Cards/Update/${id}`, {
            method: 'PUT',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                id: id,
                Title: "UpdatedCard",
                Description: "UpdatedCard",
                Stage: 0,
                Tag: 0
            })
        })
            .then(response => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    // atualização bem-sucedida, redirecionar para a página inicial
                    window.location.href = '/Cards/Index';
                } else {
                    // atualização falhou, lidar com o erro
                    console.error('Error updating card.');
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }



</script>
```

And when I call the UpdateCard function in the cshtml I get two errors in the console:
PUT https://localhost:44307/Cards/Update/9 net::ERR_ABORTED 400
Error updating card.

Note: The Delete Function works
Can you look at my simple code and point out where the error might be?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, could you please provide the `CardsModel` as well?

Comment: Sorry about it, its a public class
public class CardsModel {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int Stage { get; set; }
        public int Tag { get; set; }
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are applying the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.validateantiforgerytokenattribute) to the `Update` action, you would need to include the antiforgery token in the request as shown in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-6.0). As you are building an API, it is recommended to protect the endpoints using authorization instead, see e.g. this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70559557/7217806) for details about that.