# How to produce Antiforgery Token in blazor Server and blazor WebAssembly in .Net 8.0 in an Client Server Architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, blazor, blazor-server-side

As our application is crossed from the Coverity Scan , there was an high impact in the application says that the CSRF attack is found. In order to prevent CSRF attacks I tired to implement the Antiforgery token concept in our blazor webassembly and blazor Server as an client - Server architecture. Where I couldn't able to find the hidden input field from the  Component and there is no value is generated.

In client I have added the  Component inside the form tag

```
<form method = "post"@onsubmit="UpdateInputs">
     <AntiforgeryToken/>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Ok</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" @onclick="clear">Cancel</button>    
 </form>
```

but there is no input hidden field is appeared while the form is submitted.

In Server I added the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] in the controller and in Program.cs file I added the

builder.Services.AddAntiforgery();
app.UseAntiforgery();

What Am I missing or What i need to do with above code, to produce the antiforgery token.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, according to your description, the blazor server app plays the role of a backend which looks like a web API, and you also confirmed that it's **client-server architecture**, so that it **is not necessary to implement Anti-Forgery Token protection against CSRF Attacks**. As the web api is stateless, it doesn't setup a user session with the client. Here's the description about [Prevent Cross-site Request Forgery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-8.0) from microsoft, you shall find it related to browser-server session. This usually happened in MVC app or razor page webapp, for blazor wsam(SPA) + backend server API, we should handle it  following [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-8.0#javascript-ajax-and-spas) and [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#antiforgery-support). I recommend using  access token mechanism to secure the backend server.

By the way, in MVC project, antiforgery mechanism is used by default, when we submit form, the anti-forgery key will be submitted by the hidden input just like what you said, but in blazor wsam, we still need to create a submit method to send the http request, which [should use code below](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?view=aspnetcore-8.0#antiforgery-support) at least, instead of adding  `<AntiforgeryToken/>` component.

```
private async Task OnSubmit()
{
    var antiforgery = Antiforgery.GetAntiforgeryToken();
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "action");
    request.Headers.Add("RequestVerificationToken", antiforgery.RequestToken);
    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    ...
}
```

Comment: In the meantime, I also found this [high voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70559791) which said: `it is not necessary to implement Anti-Forgery Token protection against CSRF Attacks when building an API because how APIs are built and intended to be used, they require different methods of protection like:using API Keys.using Basic Authentication.using OpenID Connect.`

Comment: If you have gpt, you might also try to ask it "Does web api require to add Antiforgery Token mechanism to prevent CSRF attack?" and AI will also give you a vivid explanation about it. If I misunderstand your requirement, pls correct me.

Comment: (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?view=aspnetcore-8.0#antiforgery-support) according to this document I try to use  the AntiforgeryStateProvider  in client side to generate the token but in client it is not possible to use httpContext where in  alternate I tired to use httpContextAccessor.HttpContext like code will be 

@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor; 
var TokenSet = Antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext); 
 
 the return value is getting null. So what can I do further and thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Hi, the section you shared doesn't contain code about `HttpContext`. Do you get any errors when using the codes shared in the document?

Comment: hi, Yes, I'm getting syntax error in the antiforgery.RequestToken

 var antiforgery = AntiforgeryStateProvider.GetAntiforgeryToken();
 request.Headers.Add("RequestVerificationToken", antiforgery.RequestToken);

AntiforgeryRequestToken does not contain a definition for RequestToken and no accessible extension method RequestToken.  In the antiforgery variable I can able to get the FormFieldName and Value alone.

Comment: could you please share all the related code in your question so that I could have a test in my side?

Comment: Sure , I  have set up a sample application with a POST API https://github.com/meenaviji/Antiforgery/tree/0da6f05847b70ff16f2669e28788fa99117007c7 you can just try to produce the token in the request and handle the token in the server. thanks in advance

Comment: I think I should recommend you not to use AntiforgeryToken in client - Server architecture.....

Comment: Okay! So is there any good way to prevent CSRF attack in client - Server ! Architecture