# axios.post correct path param

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, axios

Super newbie to ASP.NET Core with React,
and try to build "upload file" functions.

From my react component,
I have input as follows, and trigger UploadFile function

```
<input type="file" onChange={(event) => UploadFile(event)} />
```

and in UploadFile function, it looks like this

```
    function UploadFile(e) {
        var file = e.target.files[0];
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", file);
        axios.post("/FileUpload/SingleFile", formData);
    }
```

and the controller for SingleFile looks like this

```
        public IActionResult SingleFile(IFormFile file)
        {
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(_dir, "file.png"), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                file.CopyTo(fileStream);
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

But having a bit tricky time to figure out what is the right url path to pass on to the 
axios.post(???, formData).

Is the path should be
"/'controller name'/'IActionResult method name'"??

With the current path, I get an 404 error which means wrong path.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

The path I had was correct, 
but the problem was that I was using ASP.NET Core 3.0 
so I need to generate the antiforgery token.

The answer is listed here
[Enable Antiforgery Token with ASP.NET Core and JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40530474/enable-antiforgery-token-with-asp-net-core-and-jquery/47633056#47633056)