# Identify angular js AJAX calls in ASP.NET MVC code

Tags: ajax, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a sample application using ASP.NET MVC and AngularJS.

In server side code , I have written a Action filter attribute , and in that I need to check whether the request is a normal request(Browser) or AJAX request.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    if ( filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
     {

     }
}
```

The method mentioned in the above code snippet "IsAjaxRequest()" is not returning TRUE in case of AJAX request made using $http Angular service.

I observed that the request does not have X-Requested-With header , and even adding the header did not solve the request.

Note : This is NOT CORS call.

So My question.

1. How does filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest() decide whether the request is AJAX or not?
2. I can check the request header(whether it has a particular header or not) and decide whether the request is AJAX or not. Is it the right and only approach?

Comment: Just an fyi that it's open source and you can look at the actual implementation: https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/AjaxRequestExtensions.cs

Comment: @Keith Rousseau Link provided should be helpful for me in the future..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It decides by looking whether `X-Requested-With` header exists or not.
You can add `X-Request-With` header manually to `$http` service.

Individual request

```
$http.get('/controller/action', {
   headers: {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
   }
});
```

For every request

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
}]);
```

You can see why it is missing from [Angular](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/3a75b1124d062f64093a90b26630938558909e8d)

Comment: In fact I did add the header suggested , but the issue was with the value of header , instead of  "XMLHttpRequest" it was "true" , God knows why I gave that value :). 
Link provided is also helpful. 
Thanks.