# ASP.net MVC AntiForgeryToken

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've been adding `AntiForgeryToken` to my site, but I keep getting to errors
which refer to my login page (POST)

1. "The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present."
2. The provided anti-forgery token was meant for user "", but the current user is "userXYZ".

My Login page is like so:

```
<form action="~/Login" method="post">
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
...
</form>

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(login a)
{
}
```

I've looked at this:

[The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present Error in user Registration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102957/the-required-anti-forgery-form-field-requestverificationtoken-is-not-present)

and this 
 [Anti forgery token is meant for user "" but the current user is "username"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970102/anti-forgery-token-is-meant-for-user-but-the-current-user-is-username)

But it's not clear to me what the answer is?

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried all of the proposed solutions in the first link?  Checked your web.config and solution properties? Tried using @using(Html.BeginForm())?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I have solved\fixed my second question.

So the user would login, then press back, login in again and then get

> "The provided anti-forgery token was meant for user "", but the
>   current user is "userXYZ"."

So an exception was actually being thrown in my dependency injection, it was asking for a controller which does not exist.
So I found this site http://www.learnsharecorner.com/asp-net/fixed-httpantiforgeryexception-the-provided-anti-forgery-token-was-meant-for-user-but-the-current-user-is-username/

placed the following on my GET

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "None")]
```

And the issue has gone (tho would like to get the bottom of it still).

Tho still seeking a solution to question 1?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am hitting it now, and I don't understand it