# __requestverificationtoken error in javascript vue, MVC 5

Tags: javascript, vue.js, validation, model-view-controller

I am attempting to use the **ValidateAntiForgeryToken** to prevent cross site forgery on my application.  Keep getting the error

**the required anti-forgery form field __requestverificationtoken is not present**

Been seeing a lot of chatter on this but I have been unable to come up with a solution.

The code:

in my Index.cshtml, setting the AntiForgeryToken:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "__AjaxAntiForgeryForm" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    }
```

in my ajax.utilities **post** method, setting the token:

```
var post = function (options, callbacks) {
    // set default POST options
    options.type = "POST";
    options.dataType = options.dataType !== undefined ? options.dataType : "json";
    options.contentType = options.contentType !== undefined ? options.contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8";

    var form = $('#__AjaxAntiForgeryForm');
    var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', form).val();

    return sendRequest(options, callbacks);
};
```

my jquery sets the header properly i.e. "X-Requested-With":

```
            if ( !options.crossDomain && !headers[ "X-Requested-With" ] ) {
                headers[ "X-Requested-With" ] = "XMLHttpRequest";
            }
```

finally in my controller I designate the HttpPost and ValidateAntiForgery attributes:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public  ActionResult CreateComposite(string name, int compositeTypeId, int componentTypeId, DateTime inceptionDate)
    {           
        return DispatchCommandWithJsonReturn(new CompositeCommands.CreateComposite(name, compositeTypeId, componentTypeId, inceptionDate));
    }
```

I still get the error **the required anti-forgery form field __requestverificationtoken is not present**

Using MVC 5, I don't know if that is relevant

Any ideas what is wrong?

edit:  I've seen this issue elsewhere on the site, tried to make edits suggested, to no avail.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The required anti-forgery form field "\_\_RequestVerificationToken" is not present Error in user Registration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102957/the-required-anti-forgery-form-field-requestverificationtoken-is-not-present)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but in case someone is having a problem like mine, in my case the issue was in the tag of the form, I had to add `enctype = "multipart/form-data"`, so when I add the __RequestVerificationToken value to my ajax call data it will work.